# How to add a custom matchOutcome in GKTurnBasedMatchOutcome?

Tags: ios, ios7, game-center

I have a game in which the match ends in multiple ways, each one I have set using GKturnBasedMatchOutcome. Now I need to add one more to the present list. I have looked the custom range. But I couldn't understand how to do it. Please help. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103292/how-to-implement-gkturnbasedmatchoutcomecustomrange) answer, but that is giving a crash.

I ve also tried this one

```
typedef enum
{
    GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeCancel       = 10 | GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeCustomRange,
} GKTurnBasedMatchOutcome_Custom;
```